# Cannot GET (Passed url as parameter)

Tags: node.js, express

Can routes in express not take a full URL as a parameter?

For example,

```
router.get("/new/:url", <some function>);
```

gives me the Cannot GET error when the :url is https://www.google.com

Answer (score 1):

> You can't get full `URL` like this format.This type of format is used to take parameters send by client

```
 router.get("/new/:url", <some function>);
    //you can get url as params
    req.params.url//Use your URL
```

Comment: The url IS a parameter being sent by the client

Comment: yes, it assumes as a parameter you can use that parameter but can't use as full URL in current route

Answer (score 1):

You should encode url parameter before sending. Your example encoded would be Http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com. On server side you can decode parameter to get value from before.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not much aware about [ExpressJS routing](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html) because your url https://www.google.com have **`//`** which is used route separation.

In you case, we know that [ExpressJS](https://expressjs.com/) support regex route. I think following regex will work for you

```
app.get("/new/:protocol(http:|https:|ftp:)?/?/:url", <some function>);
```

In above case, you have bunded with limited protocol http, https and ftp. You may add more protocol by using **`|`** separator( or condition) and even you don't know what would be protocol then you like following

```
app.get("/new/:protocol?/?/:url", <some function>);
```

In above both route, **`?`** means option that routes works file for

- /new/www.google.com
- /new/https://www.google.com

and in your function, you may append protocol in url like

```
function newUrl(req, res) {
    if(req.params.protocol)
        req.params.url = req.params.protocol + '//' + req.params.url;
    console.log(req.params.url);
}
```